# How to compare list A and B and return yes if any sublist of B is in A

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

Assume there are two lists `A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]` and `B=[[1,2,3],[5,6,4],[7,1,9]]`. I want to compare these two lists  and return `yes` if any sub list of B is in A and if not return `no`. Also, I want 2nd sublist of B which is `[5,6,4]` returns `yes` since it has all items of 2nd sub list of A which is `[4,5,6]`.

Therefore, output should be like below:

```
yes
yes
no
```

This is the code:

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
B=[[1,2,3],[5,6,4],[7,1,9]] 
     
for i in range(len(B)):
    if B[i] in A:
        print('yes')
        
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: are we allowed to cheat a bit to get you the code working?

Comment: `if any(sorted(sublist) in A for sublist in B):`

Comment: @Matthias yeh :p that is the cheat i was asking abt

Comment: And if we need both sorted: `any(sorted(sublist) in (sorted(sublist) for sublist in A) for sublist in B)` (yes, we can use the name `sublist` twice)

Comment: @ Matthias, it is not grantee that list A is sorted.

Comment: @Aras That's why my second solution sorts it on the fly

Comment: @ Matthias, it prints yes for all of them.

Comment: Are the numbers in the sublists unique?

Comment: @Nick, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @Aras for example, is `[3,2,3]` a valid sublist?

Comment: @Nick, so sublits are always unique.

Comment: I am wondering is there any way than sorting?

Comment: @Aras see my answer for an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort data A and data B in one go in the same loop:

```
A=[[1,3,2],[4,6,5],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]] #I messed up A as well
B=[[1,2,3],[5,6,4],[7,1,9]] 
     
for i in range(len(B)):
    if sorted(B[i]) in map(sorted,A):
        print('yes')
        
    else:
        print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in B:
    i.sort()
    c=0
    for k in A:
        k.sort()
        if i==k:
           c+=1
    if c>0:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Not too fancy, but does the job.
`c` is used as a counter to achieve the single print only. You can do it maybe in a fancier way using `break`, however, we might need the help of someone more experienced than I am.

To make it work, for each element in `B` and in `A` we sort it right after its extraction from the list. Then we compare them.

`c` is included in the first loop, so we can reset it on every entry.

The `printing` has to be made after finishing the `second loop` but surely, before entering the first loop again.